# Why does my footer not have 100% width on some pages?

Tags: html, css, footer

The same footer code is used for every page on my site. How come the footer only actually shows up as 100% width on two of the pages?

I have tried many different fixes, but nothing seems to be working.

HTML:

```
<div id="footer-outer">
<footer class="wrapper">
    <div class="ftr-nav-area">
        <div class="l-f-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">branding</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="r-f-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">staffing solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">social media consulting</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="socal-section">
        <div class="s-text">
        <h4>Contact Us</h4>
        <p>In a est nisl. Vestibulum condimentum, neque id faucibus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="s-icon">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/twiter-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/fb-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/g-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-logo-section">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/footer-logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        <p class="t-gap-10">&copy; Copyright. 2013. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
#outer{
width: 1000px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px auto;
clear: both;}

#footer-outer{
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border-top: 1px solid #31679c;
background: url(../images/footer-bg.jpg) repeat-x top #0066b3;
color: #8eddff;
float: left;}

.wrapper{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
clear: both;
padding: 22px 0px 16px;
overflow: hidden;}

.l-f-nav{ width:123px; float:left;}
.r-f-nav{ width:180px; float:left;}
.ftr-nav-area ul{ list-style:none;}
.ftr-nav-area ul li{ padding:0px 0px 12px 22px; background:url(../images/footer-        icon.png) no-repeat 4px 6px;}
.ftr-nav-area ul li a{ color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
.ftr-nav-area ul li a:hover{ color:#7bcdf5;}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.wrapper` has width of `width: 1000px;` not 100%.

Comment: [1] I guess unclosed #footer-outer div is only an omission in the question? [2] .wrapper has a width of 1000px, why do you expect it to fill the page? [3] A jsfiddle would be great if this is not the problem.

Comment: It is true that .wrapper will only expand to 1000px. HOWEVer, I think the OP intended this and only wants #footer-outer div to expand 100%. Remove float declartion in #footer-outer. This will shrink wrap your content instead of taking the full 100% width.

Comment: Removing float didn't change anything, but what I think the problem may be now, is that my wrapper is covering the footer and making it look like it isn't extending all the way. I don't know why this would only happen on two of the pages though.